# Memory leaks - ProofReader

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

I have a problem to identify my memory leak.
In Instruments, I can see a leaked Object:can't

```
Leaked Object: Malloc 16 bytes
Size: 16Bytes
Responsible Library: ProofReader
Responsible Frame: PRRfInit
```

I can't identify this leak, maybe somebody has an idea?

Thanks a lot.
Sahid

Comment: if you open the extended view (maybe it's called detailed view, can't recall)...the tool will show you the exact line

Comment: Yes i have tried but it is in Assembly language. But the good news is the leak appends only in Debug mode.

Comment: I have the same situation with debug or release, with gdb or lldb whenever I open a view controller on iPad simulator 5.0